# How can I terminate a remote process that I launched with a python subprocess?

Tags: python, linux, subprocess, remote-access, kill-process

First just for reference here is an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4791612/4451521) to the question  "How to terminate a python subprocess launched with shell=True"

In this the user is launching a subprocess and he wants to terminate it later. I have tried it, it works fine.

Now, I want to do something similar but in a remote machine. The remote machine can be accessed through ssh with no problem.

so I have

```
import os
import signal
import subprocess
import time


SERVER = "remote_server"

#Here initiate a subprocess that measures the cpu but this time remotely
pro= subprocess.Popen("ssh "+SERVER+ " sar -u 1 > mylog.log")

time.sleep(10)

#here kill the process (what should I put HERE??
#Kill the remote process
```

As you can see I initiate a process that runs `sar -u 1 > mylog.log` in a remote machine. This process will start running 
After 10 secs, I want the remote process to stop. How do I kill it??

I think putting simply `os.killpg(os.getpgid(pro.pid), signal.SIGTERM)` would not kill it, would it?

Comment: Did Hack5's solution below work for this use case?
I'm looking for a solution for the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is `proc.terminate()` or `proc.kill()` (prefer the first one)

See https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.kill

Your remote program will be killed, because SSH automatically kills off processes that are no longer associated with an SSH session (which most people find out the hard way)

Comment: you mean remotely? (through another Popen)?

Comment: so if I kill the SSH process , I will be killing also the process in the remote?

Comment: Yes, because the other end of the ssh connection (the daemon) will terminate unused stuff. That's an implementation detail though, you should avoid using it

Comment: if I should avoid it, is there an alternative?

Comment: If you control the remote program, you could program it to read from stdin and exit if it receives any newline character - then you can use `proc.stdin.write("\n")` and it will terminate - but of course that won't work if it crashes. Alternatively, it could write its own PID to stdout, and you can read it, and use a remote `kill` command over ssh, but it's also fallible.